# Getting a difference between time(n+1)-time(n) in a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataset

I have a dataframe where the columns represent monthly data and the rows different simulations. the data I am working with accumulates over time so I want to take the difference between the months to get the true value for that month. There are not headers for my data frame

For  example:

```
View(df)=

1  3  4  6  19  23  24  25  26 ...
1  2  3  4  5   6   7   8   9  ...
0  0  2  3  5   7   14  14  14 ...
```

My plan was to use the `diff()` function or something like it, but I am having trouble using it on a dataframe.

I have tried:

```
df1<-diff(df, lag = 1, differences = 1)
```

but only get zeros.

I am grateful for any advice.

Comment: "*There are not headers for my data frame*" -- seems unlikely... Perhaps it's not a data frame? Maybe it's a matrix? Regardless, try `apply(df, 1, diff)`.

Comment: And coding questions fit better on Stack Overflow - there doesn't seem to be anything statistical in this question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and sorry for posting it here!

Comment: It would be best to include a minimal reproducible example so that we could show you that our suggestions work on your example.

Answer (score 1):

see `?apply`. If it's a data frame

```
apply(df,2,diff)
```

should work. Also since a dataframe is a list of vectors `sapply(df,diff)` should work.